# Changing only arrow direction on y axis

Tags: pgfplots, formatting

I want to change the direction of the arrow at y axis, so that 0 still starts from the top and minus increases in direction of the arrow. here is the code (I am having more charts thats why I added `groupplot`, but to make it easier for you i deleted them):

```
  \usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
  \usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{tikzpicture}
      \pgfplotsset{%
%  width=4cm,
%  height=2cm,
%  scale only axis,
  ymajorgrids,
  yminorgrids,
  y axis line style = ultra thick,
  nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny,black},
    axis y line  = left,    
    y axis line style = ultra thick,
    ybar legend,
    axis on top=false,
    %y dir=reverse,
    %allow reversal of rel axis cs=false,
}  

\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group name=my plots,
        group size=1 by 11,
        xlabels at=edge bottom,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,
        vertical sep=12pt,                
    },
    ybar,
    footnotesize,
    width=8cm,
    height=3cm,
    xlabel=Site,
    xmin=0, xmax=6,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels={Variante1,Variante2,Variante3,Variante4,Variante5},
    x tick label style={rotate=-90,anchor=west},
    ylabel style={rotate=-90},
    tickpos=left,
    ytick align=outside,
    xtick align=outside,   
    axis on top=false,     
]      

      \nextgroupplot[ymax=0.0,ymin=-2500]
      \addplot[black, pattern color=black,
        %bar shift=2.5mm,
        fill=blue,
        postaction={
        pattern=north east lines
        },
        draw,
      ] coordinates { (1, -773.8) (2, -1875.6) (3,-1879.76) (4,-1271.16)(5,-1274.92) };

      \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is the output:

[image]

but it should look like this:

[image]

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

You can use

```
    y axis line style = {ultra thick,stealth-},
```

(the default style uses `-stealth`).

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
      \pgfplotsset{%
%  width=4cm,
%  height=2cm,
%  scale only axis,
  ymajorgrids,
  yminorgrids,
  y axis line style = ultra thick,
  nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny,black},
    axis y line  = left,    
    y axis line style = {ultra thick,stealth-},
    ybar legend,
    axis on top=false,
    %y dir=reverse,
    %allow reversal of rel axis cs=false,
}  

\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group name=my plots,
        group size=1 by 11,
        xlabels at=edge bottom,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,
        vertical sep=12pt,                
    },
    ybar,
    footnotesize,
    width=8cm,
    height=3cm,
    xlabel=Site,
    xmin=0, xmax=6,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels={Variante1,Variante2,Variante3,Variante4,Variante5},
    x tick label style={rotate=-90,anchor=west},
    ylabel style={rotate=-90},
    tickpos=left,
    ytick align=outside,
    xtick align=outside,   
    axis on top=false,     
]      

      \nextgroupplot[ymax=0.0,ymin=-2500]
      \addplot[black, pattern color=black,
        %bar shift=2.5mm,
        fill=blue,
        postaction={
        pattern=north east lines
        },
        draw,
      ] coordinates { (1, -773.8) (2, -1875.6) (3,-1879.76) (4,-1271.16)(5,-1274.92) };

      \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: wow, thank you very much, couldn't imagine that is so easy !!!

Comment: @ives You're welcome! Don't forget that you can accept the answer, by clicking the checkmark to the left, if you consider it solved your problem. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).